# Convert a Oracle Stored procedure with "Connect By" and "TYPE" to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, cursor

I have difficulty to convert an oracle SP to the one in MySQL. Especially, for "Connect by" and "TYPE".

Here is the problem to solve using an Oracle stored procedure.

There is a table with 3 columns

```
ID  |Last_Modified | Flag   
1   |2011-12-11 02:00:00|   0   
2   |2011-12-13 02:00:00|   0   
3   |2011-12-02 02:00:00|   0 
4   |2011-12-12 02:00:00|   0
```

the stored procedure “getback(String pId, String pLast_Modified). E.g. pId =”1,2,3” and pLast_Modified = “2011-12-11 02:00:00, 2011-12-13 02:00:00, 2011-12-01 02:00:00”.

The logic is that, for the same ID, if the last_modified in the table is later than the passed last_modified, then set the flag for that record to “1”.

Here is Oracle stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure test1(
p_ids varchar2,   
p_dates varchar2  
) IS

TYPE id_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
TYPE date_type IS TABLE OF DATE INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);

ids id_type;
last_updated date_type;
lvar1 varchar2(200);
lvar2 varchar2(200);



cursor c1 is 
With ids as (select rownum id, regexp_substr(p_ids,'[^,]+', 1, level) val from dual
connect by regexp_substr(p_ids, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null), 
lupdated as (select rownum id, regexp_substr(p_dates,'[^,]+', 1, level) val from dual
connect by regexp_substr(p_dates, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
select lut.id, 
case when lut.last_updated > to_date(lu.val,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') then 1
          else 0
end flag
from last_updated_tbl lut,ids,lupdated lu
where lut.id = ids.val
and   ids.id = lu.id
;

BEGIN
open c1;
loop
 fetch c1 into lvar1,lvar2;
 exit when c1%notfound;

 dbms_output.put_line(lvar1||' flag:'||lvar2);

end loop;

close c1;

END;
```